# Do the critical points $p'(z)=0$ of a complex polynomial $p(z)$ all lie inside the region $L=\{z\mid |p(z)|<1\}$ if $\partial L$ is a Jordan curve?

Tags: complex-analysis

From Gauss-Lucas theorem, I know that all the critical points lie inside the convex hull of all the roots of $p(z)$, which implies that all the critical points are inside the convex hull of all the roots of $p(z)-\exp(i t) $, for $t\in [0,2\pi)$. However the region $L$ in itself is usually not a convex set. I could not generalize the Gauss-Lucas theorem to this general case.

I have experimentally verified a lot of examples and they all satisfy the claim. I wonder why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It suffices to require that $L$ is connected. Due to the maximum modulus principle, $L$ is simply connected, and $p$ is a proper map from $L$ to the unit disk.

One can now apply the Riemann-Hurwitz formula in the following form:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be domains on the Riemann sphere of finite connectivity $m$ and $n$, respectively, and let $f : V \to W$ be a $k$-sheeted (ramified) proper map having $r$ critical points (counted by multiplicity). Then $$ m − 2 = k(n − 2) + r \, .$$

(Source: [Steinmetz, Norbert. (1993). The formula of riemann-hurwitz and iteration of rational functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations. 22. 203-206. 10.1080/17476939308814660.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233235727_The_formula_of_riemann-hurwitz_and_iteration_of_rational_functions))

In our case is $m=n=1$ and $k = \deg p$. It follows that $r = \deg p - 1$, i.e. all zeros of the derivative (counted with multiplicity) are in $L$.